# Show Disassembly without Debugging in MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, vectorization, disassembly

I can run my code and if debugger is halted I can show the disassembly of the current code. (Debugging->Window->Disassembly)

But I want to see the disassembly of the compiled code without running the code. I want to see the disassembly of some function bodies. I want to see how and if the code is optimized/vectorized.

Is there a built in tool in MS Visual Studio to see the disassembly of some C++ code only by compiling the project but without debugging it?

Comment: I know the option of /Qvec-report:{1}{2} to inform about vectorization, but i want the disassembly itself